# Cannot move Android seekBar using Appium Python

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, python-appium

I have a simple app which contains a SeekBar, which I want to drag up untill the end.

[image]

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799788/cant-move-android-seekbar-with-appium) SO post, I added this code block

```
get_seekbar = driver.find_element_by_class_name('android.widget.SeekBar')
start = get_seekbar.location.get('x')
print(start)

end = get_seekbar.size.get('width')
print(end)

ycd = get_seekbar.location.get('y')
print(ycd)

TouchAction.tap(get_seekbar).move_to(end,ycd).release().perform()
#Tried it with press and long_press methods also but got same error
#TouchAction.press(get_seekbar).move_to(end,ycd).release().perform()

time.sleep(5)
```

which throws this error in the console -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zac/PycharmProjects/appiumdemo/cute_dogs.py", line 56, in <module>
    TouchAction.tap(get_seekbar).move_to(end,ycd).release().perform()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appium/webdriver/common/touch_action.py", line 44, in tap
    opts = self._get_opts(element, x, y)
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute '_get_opts'
```

What am I doing incorrectly here? I tried providing the element in the `move_to` method which again raised another exception.

What's the correct approach to handle such a seekBar? For reference, the debug apk can be found on this [link](https://mega.nz/#F!nq42VSRI!l-EC000r9fS9LT4sEYOKbA).